# Division in finite fields

Tags: arithmetic, finite-fields

Let's take $GF(2^3)$ as and the irreducible polynomial $p(x) = x^3+x+1$ as an example. This is the multiplication table of the finite field[image]

I can easily do some multiplication such as $$(x^2+x)\cdot(x+1) = x^3 + x^2 + x +1 = x+1+x^2+x+2 = x^2$$

I am wondering how to divide some random fields such as $x^2 / (x+1)$. The result is $x^2+x$ (compare above). But how do I actually calculate this. Polynomial long division does not help be:

[image]

1. Why don't I get $x+1$ as result?
2. How can I calculate $x / (x^2+x+1)$? The result should be $x+1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since any element of this field can be written as $ax^2+bx+c$ we write:

$\frac{x}{x^2+x+1}=ax^2+bx+c$

$x=(ax^2+bx+c)*(x^2+x+1)$

$x=ax^4+(a+b)x^3+(a+b+c)x^2+(b+c)x+c$

Use the fact that $x^3=x+1$ to further simplify.

$x=a(x^2+x)+(a+b)(x+1)+(a+b+c)x^2+(b+c)x+c$

$x=(b+c)x^2+(c)x+(a+b+c)$

Now solve for $a$, $b$, and $c$ by comparing each power of $x$.

$b+c=0$

$c=1$

$a+b+c=0$

Thus, $a=0$, $b=1$, and $c=1$.

So $\frac{x}{x^2+x+1}=x+1$

Answer (score 1):

If we have a field $K = F[X]/p(X)$, then we can compute the inverse of $\overline{q(X)}$ in $K$ as follows.

Since $p$ is irreducible, either $q$ is zero in $K$ or $(p,q)=1$. By the Euclidean algorithm, we can find $a,b$ such that $a(X)p(X) + b(X)q(X) = 1$.  Then $\overline{b(X)} \cdot \overline{q(X)} = \overline{1}$, so $\overline{b(X)}$ is the inverse of $\overline{q(X)}$.

In your example, the Euclidean algorithm gives us $(x+1)(x^3 + x + 1) + (x^2)(x^2 + x+1) = 1$ (modulo 2), so $(x^2+x+1)^{-1} = x^2$ and $\frac{x}{x^2+x+1} = x(x^2) = x^3 = x+1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You just go the other way around. If $a = bc$ then b and c are on the row and column and a is inside the table. So if $a/c = b$ the same should hold. Now see what c and a and b are for your example and go check in the table.

---

So for example 2) you check which row will give you $x$ inside the table for the column with $x^2+x+1$ on top.

Comment: Is there any way to actually calculate the result? Your lookup approach sounds good, but if the finite field is too large it may be too expensive to precalculate the whole multiplication table.

Comment: I don't know if there is another way. Multiplication is defined through the multiplication table and division is the inverse to multiplication so without a multiplication table I don't know how to do it. If we haven't yet decided what multiplication does we can't know what division would  do  since division goes the other direction. Maybe there is a short-cut for finite fields, but I'm no expert of them.